# How to override an XML element with the differences in another?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have different XML configruations depending on the type of panel I'm connecting to.

Most panels have the same configuration, but the differences lie in the newer versions.

e.g.

The version 1.0 panel has the following

```
  <panel version="1.0">
    <options opt1="1823" opt2="7" opt3="127"/>
    <timers>
      <t1 min="0" max="99" />
      <t2 min="0" max="99" />      
    </timers>
  </panel>
```

and version 1.1 has the exact same configuration, except it has a different value for `opt1`.

```
  <panel version="1.1">
    <options opt1="7967" /> <!-- opt2 and opt3 are exactly the same -->
    <!-- the timer values are all exactly the same -->
  </panel>
```

**Question**
Is there a way for me to load the configuration for panel 1.0 and automatically override the differences from panel 1.1? I.e. is there something built into the .net framework to compare 2 xml files and override 1 with the differences in another?

If not, I could copy the configuration from panel 1.0 into panel 1.1, but that's duplicating a lot of data and I'm trying to avoid that.

I could also load panel 1.0 first, and then search for any elements in 1.1 that have to be overridden. But if that wheel has already been invented I don't want to reinvent it.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
foreach (var el in panelV11.Descendants())
{
    var elName = el.Name;
    foreach (var attrib in el.Attributes())
    {
        var attrName = attrib.Name;

        panelV10.Element(elName).Attribute(attrName).Value = attrib.Value;
    }
}
```

And then just use `panelV10` as the main configuration file, with the old values overwritten by the new values from the 1.1 file.